# Openlayers3 - reproject a point from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:2193

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers

I need to reproject a point from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:2193.I tried to achieve that doing the following:

Updated: Here is the little Angular2 service that I wrote: It takes a coordinate and and tries to reproject it. Afterwards it returns a filter string.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {OlService} from './ol.service';

@Injectable()
export class OlFilterService {

constructor(private olService: OlService) {

}

pip = (coords: [number,number]) => {
    let ol = this.olService.get();



    let reprojectedCoords = ol.proj.transform(coords, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:2193');


    let filter = 'Intersects(the_geom,POINT(' + reprojectedCoords + '))';


    return filter;


}
```

}

This code silently fails on me. I just don't get anything or 'false' back. Is it simply not possible or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you post your complete code so we can see where exactly the problem ?

Comment: Hi Shiko
Done that. It is a little service within an Angular2 project.

Comment: Did you check the ol object if is null, also the return of 'reprojectedCoords' is it null or false ? Also verify that you are getting the coordinates correct.

Comment: Hi Shiko
Thanks for your answers:
Yes - the ol object is properly created.
Yes - the coordinates are also correct.
To test that I changed the project statement to reporject into 3857, which is working fine

Comment: good to hear it is working now

Comment: The projection from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857 works
The projection from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3293  does not work

Comment: Can you try **ol.proj.fromLonLat**  like ol.proj.fromLonLat(coords , 'EPSG:2193' )   http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/apidoc/ol.proj.html#.fromLonLat

Comment: May be ol doesn't recognize your projection. Try to add the projection definition for 'EPSG:2193' using proj4

Comment: What are you putting in as coords?

Comment: @itsyahani

Yes - I do believe you are right. Openlayers does not recognize the projection definition. I tried to add it like this 

    proj4.defs('EPSG:2193','+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=173 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1600000 +y_0=10000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs');

But still no luck. I reprojected my layer into EPSG:3857 meanwhile... But still would love to solve this problem

Comment: after adding proj4 def, did you add the projection to ol like this?  var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({ code: 'EPSG:2193', units: 'm'    });
ol.proj.addProjection(projection);
It should work. It did for me.

Answer (score 1):

itsyahani is right, openlayers doesn't recognise EPSG:2193 out of the box. You'll need to add the projection in your code.

First include openlayers and proj.js:

```
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.4.2/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.4.4/proj4.js"></script>
```

Now in your script define the projection and its extents:

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:2193","+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=173 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1600000 +y_0=10000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +axis=neu");
var projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:2193');
projection.setExtent([827933.23, 3729820.29, 3195373.59, 7039943.58]);
ol.proj.addProjection(projection);
```

You can now use EPSG:2193 like any other projection.